# Magento2 : You don't have permission to access js on shared hosting

Tags: magento2

When I open the console, I find many errors related to js files not being accessed and when I click on any file I get

> You don't have permission to access /pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/fr_FR/underscore.js on this server

I tried to change files/folders permissions to check, I even set permissions to 777 on everything but still the same problem. On my local machine, everything is working fine but on the shared server I still have issues only with js files and icons in the backend. css files are loaded.

Any help would be really appreciated as I'm struggling with this for a week now.

Comment: My first guess, you have some troubles with "follow symlinks" configuration (since css files are copied, while js are symlinked by default).  You can check that by running deploy command (bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy), so real hard copies will be created in `pub/static` instead of symlinks (or just manually copy real file into some pub/static subfolder and check if you can browse it from web).

Comment: Hi @VKorotun, yes you're right. That was exactly that. Can you make it as an answer so that I can accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check "follow symlinks" configuration on your server. All JavaScript files are symlinked by default, while the most of css files are copied (since generated out from LESS sources). You can check that by running deploy command (bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy), so real hard copies will be created in pub/static instead of symlinks (or just manually copy real file into some pub/static subfolder and check if you can browse it from web).